# Were Injured Clone Troopers Put in a "Cheaper to Replace" Category?

Tags: star-wars

I'm sure there's a proper term for this concept where, when something is damaged, replacement cost is cheaper than repair cost.

Was there a point, for clone troopers, where the Republic considered it too expensive to allow them to heal?  And if so, was it more about the cost of an operation or the length of time of convalescence?  And is there anything supporting that the Empire would be tighter on this limit than the Republic?

Comment: In a universe where bacta is as potent and effective as we see in ESB and the EU, 'convalescence' sorta loses all meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one of the early episodes in Season One of The Clone Wars (cartoon), the Republic spends quite a bit of resources guarding a medical station in the Outer Rim where clone troopers are sent to heal.

In fact, Count Dooku and General Grievous have a discussion about ambushing the Republic reinforcements due how predictable the Jedi are because they place such high value on the lives of their troops.

On the other side, Grievous is constantly destroying his own droids (I know they're not humans, but I think my point is still valid here) on the slightest annoyance.

We also know that clones are notoriously expensive to grow and train (which is why that model was moved away from in favor of a recruiting approach), so it seems to me that you would definitely favor repairing a trooper than just destroying all of the injured.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Kamino clones weren't necessarily more expensive than other sources, but they were much slower to create.  It took ~10 years for a group to mature.